# Array of singly linked list won't delete node

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I have an array[4] where each index of the array has a singly linked list that holds the following information: name, size. The switch statement controls what index the information will go into according to the size of the party.

Problem: When trying to delete a node according to the size (user inputs) the node will not delete.

I know that all of the cases of deletion have the proper syntax but I cannot figure out why my node will not delete. Appreciate any help.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char name[20];
    int size;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node* head[4]={NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
node* tail[4]={NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};

//
// proto's
//

void add_party(int, char name[], int size);
void delete_party(char name[], int size);
void list_parties(void);
void change_p_size(char name[], int size);


//
// main function
//

int main()
{
    int x;
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\nEnter 1 to add a party\nEnter 2 to remove a party\nEnter 3 for the list of the party\nEnter 4 to change party size.\nEnter 5 to quit.\n\n");
        // user interface
        scanf("%d",&x);
        switch(x)
        {
                char name[20]; //local variables
                int size;

            case 1:
                printf("\nParty Name: ");
                scanf("%s", name);
                printf("\nParty Size: ");
                scanf("%d", &size);
                if(size == 0)
                {
                    printf("\nThat is not a valid command. Party not added!\n");
                }
                if(size >= 1 && size <= 2)
                {
                    add_party(0, name, size);
                }
                else if(size >= 3 && size <= 4)
                {
                    add_party(1, name, size);
                }
                else if(size >= 5 && size <= 6)
                {
                    add_party(2, name, size);
                }
                else if(size >= 7)
                {
                    add_party(3, name, size);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nSize of party to delete: ");
                scanf("%i", &size);
                delete_party(NULL, size);
                break;

            case 3:
                list_parties();
                break;

            case 4:
                change_partysize();
                break;

            case 5:
                exit(0);

            default:
                continue;
        }
    }
}

//
//add function
//

void add_party(int h, char *name, int size)
{

    //create a new node
    int i=0;
    int breaker = 0;
    node *p;
    node *new_item;

    new_item = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate memory the size of the struct

    strcpy(new_item->name,name);
    new_item->size = size;

    if(head[h] == NULL && tail[h] == NULL) // if an empty list, create a head and tail
    {
        head[h] = new_item;
        tail[h] = head[h];
        new_item->next = NULL;
        return;
    }

    //traversal
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        p = head[i];
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            //check that no repeating names. delete nodes that do have repeating names
            if(strcmp(p->name,name) == 0)
            {
                printf("\nSorry, that name is already taken\n");
                free(new_item);
                return;
            }
            p = p->next; //go to the next node in the list
        }
    }
    tail[h]->next = new_item;
    new_item->next = NULL;
    tail[h] = new_item;
}

//
//delete function
//

void delete_party(char *name, int size)
{
    int i=0;
    int breaker = 0;
    node *p;
    node *previous;
    if(name != NULL)
    {
        for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        {

            p = previous = head[i]; //make sure previous trails behind head
            while(p != NULL)
            {
                int c = (strcmp(p->name,name)==0);
                if(c==0)
                {
                    breaker = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    previous = p;
                    p = p -> next;
            }
            if(breaker==1)
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int group = -1;

        if(size == 1 || size == 2)
        {
            group = 0;
        }
        if(size == 3 || size == 4)
        {
            group = 1;
        }
        if(size == 5 || size == 6)
        {
            group = 2;
        }
        if(size >= 7)
        {
            group = 3;
        }

        for(i = group; i > -1; i--)
        {
            node *p = head[i];
            node *previous = head[i];
            while(p != NULL)
            {
                if(p <= size)
                {
                    breaker = 1;
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    previous = p;
                    p = p-> next;
                }
            }
            if(breaker)
                break;
        }
    }
    if(p == NULL)
        return;
    if(head[i] == tail[i] && head[i] != NULL) // case 1, empty list
    {
        printf("\nList is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    else if(p == tail[i] && p == head[i]) // case 2, one element
    {
        head[i] = NULL;
        tail[i] = NULL;
        free(p);
    }
    else if(p == head[i]) // case 3, delete from the head
    {
        head[i] = head[i] -> next;
        tail[i] = NULL;
        free(p);
    }
    else if(p == tail[i]) // case 4, delete from tail
    {
        tail[i] = previous;
        tail[i] -> next = NULL;
        free(p);
    }
    else // case 5, delete from middle
    {
        previous -> next = p -> next;
        free(p);
    }

}

//
// list function
//

void list_parties(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    node *p=head;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        p=head[i];
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            printf("\n\n%s, %d\n\n", p->name, p->size);
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
}

//
// change function
//

void change_partysize(char *name, int size)
{
    int absolute_value = 0;
    int comparison = 0;
    int current_size = 0;
    printf("\nWhat name is your party under?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    //check if the name
    printf("\nWhat would you like to change the size to?\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    node *p;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        if(p->name == name) //new size falls into same range as the size coorelating to the name
        {
            current_size = p->size;
            absolute_value = abs(size - current_size);
            comparison = size - current_size;

            if(current_size > 7 && size > 7)
            {
                current_size = size;
                return;
            }
            else if(absolute_value >= 1)
            {
                //delete the node's value but not the name
                delete_party(NULL, size);
                //insert node with new name & dif size
                add_party(NULL, name, size);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nYou did not enter a different party size\n");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2) `change_partysize();` need arguments.

Comment: Why does `delete_party()` loop over all the groups? Shouldn't it just delete from the group for the size you give?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY If the variables had initializations it would be a problem. Declarations by themselves are OK in `switch`.

Comment: What is `if(p <= size)` supposed to do? Why are you comparing a pointer to a party size? I guess that was supposed to be `if (p->size <= size)`

Comment: @Barmar to see if the value falls outside of the range

Comment: @Barmar now I'm getting a segmentation fault after creating 3 parties and deleting one of them by size

Comment: `node *p = head[i];
            node *previous = head[i];` : `p` and `previos` are local variables in for-loop.

Comment: @ConnorBrereton Instead of putting "Solved" in the comments and title, please select the green checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you. (You will even get a few points for this.)

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings then fix those warnings.  There are lots of warnings about the 'types' using an uninitialized variable, variable set but not used, etc etc.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring new variables `p` and `previous` inside the `for` loop when you delete by `size`. So when the code after the loop uses these variables, it's using the uninitialized variables declared at the top of the function. Get rid of the declarations and just assign the variables.

Also, `if (p <= size)` appears to be a typo for `if (p->size <= size)`. I'm surprised you didn't get a compiler warning for that.

You can also replace the `if(breaker)` check with a test in the `for` header.

```
    for(i = group; !breaker && i > -1; i--)
    {
        p = head[i];
        previous = head[i];
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            if(p->size <= size)
            {
                breaker = 1;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                previous = p;
                p = p-> next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's only deleting the first node in the list and not by the size specified. I think maybe there is an issue lying in the traversal to the node with the size

Comment: It deletes the first node where `p->size <= size`. So if the user enters 6, it will delete a node from group 2 with size = 5 or 6.

Comment: And since all the nodes in group 2 should have size 5 or 6, that means it will delete the first node in the group.

Comment: Maybe you should use `p->size == size` instead of `<=`?